# CyanogenMod version number

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

Is the version number of CyanogenMod is saved anywhere in Cyanogen source tree (the code that I downloaded with **repo iint** and **repo sync**?
I downloaded CyanogenMod code a few months ago, and I'm not sure which version I downloaded (10.0 or 10.1), so I need to get the exact version.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.
The file manifest.xml under .repo directory of the root of the CM tree contains information about the version number.
The is actually a symbolic link to manifests/default.xml (under .repo).
The fourth element in this XML file (<default revision=...) is the version number (or name).